# How to print TukeyHSD to pretty table format in for example .pdf with R?

Tags: r, export, anova, txt, tukey

I can run ANOVA and TukeyHSD on my dataset, and the output can easily be saved to a txt format as such:

```
#AOV test
res.aov <- aov(variable_of_interest ~ Treatment*some_variable*some_parameter, data = dataframe)

#save output to text file
capture.output(TukeyHSD(res.aov), file="TUKEY_outfile.txt")
```

[image: Example Tukey]

However, the output is pretty ugly in my opinion, and it takes a lot of time to get it into Excel and format it into a pretty format. Is there a way to directly print the outputs to a nice table format in for example excel or .pdf? I saw a LATEX solution, but it was unfortunately very complicated.

As a working example, the following code could be used:

```
fm1 <- aov(breaks ~ wool + tension, data = warpbreaks)
capture.output(TukeyHSD(fm1), file="example_tukey.txt")
```

Comment: What exactly is a "nice" table format? The output isn't very tabular at all. What exactly do you want the output to look like? It sounds like you are just going to have to do the formatting yourself. There is no one formatting function that satisfies everyone.

Comment: Fair point. Nice table format would be to get this exact output in Excel file as an example.

Comment: Can you not open the `TUKEY_outfile.txt` file in Excel? Are you expecting everything to be in it's own cell in Excel? You can read all the data into Excel and then split the columns on whitespaces

Comment: This works indeed, I was just hoping there was an easy way to output the txt file to .pdf without going through all these steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution. If you plan to move code/output/tables/graphics from R to pdf/html/latex format files regularly, you should invest in the time to learn `Rmarkdown` or `Bookdown` which are specifically designed exactly for this purpose. If you just want to export a few tables to html or latex, the package `xtable` may work for you. The following code uses the example on the `TukeyHSD` manual page to illustrate producing an html file containing three tables:

```
fm1 <- aov(breaks ~ wool * tension, data = warpbreaks)
TK <- TukeyHSD(fm1)
print(xtable(TK$wool), type="html", file="TukeyTables.html")
cat("<p></p>", file="TukeyTables.html", append=TRUE)
print(xtable(TK$tension), type="html", file="TukeyTables.html", append=TRUE)
cat("<p></p>", file="TukeyTables.html", append=TRUE)
print(xtable(TK$'wool:tension'), type="html", file="TukeyTables.html", append=TRUE)
```

This code produces an html file with three tables will look something like the figure. There are many arguments in `xtable` function that give you substantial control over the formatting, but the package is really designed for latex.

[image: TukeyTables.html].

Comment: Thanks, exactly the sort of thing I was looking for